# gnuplot: How to avoid scaling to 0 with filledcurves?

Tags: gnuplot, fill

If I plot a filled curve `with filledcurves` gnuplot seems to always autoscale y-axis to zero.
Why? A bug? Did I miss anything? How to avoid? Any ideas?

If I do:

```
plot $Data u 1:2 w filledcurves noautoscale
```

I get the error message:

```
x range is invalid
```

Apparently, there is nothing yet to do "noautoscale" on.
If I do another plot first it also autoscales filledcurves to 0.
So, I don't see a way to autoscale a filled curve alone **not** to 0.

**Code:**

```
### how to autoscale a filled curve NOT to zero?
reset session

$Data <<EOD
3.8  3.8
9.1  3.8
9.1  9.1
3.8  9.1
3.8  3.8
EOD

unset key
set multiplot layout 1,4
    set title "with lines\n\n"
    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7
    set title "with filledcurves\n\n"
    plot $Data u 1:2 w filledcurves
    set title "with lines \\&\nwith filledcurves\n"
    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7, '' u 1:2 w filledcurves
    set title "with lines \\&\nwith filledcurves\n+noautoscale"
    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7, '' u 1:2 w filledcurves noautoscale
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an unintended consequence of accepting plot commands of the form:

```
  plot $data using x:y1:y2 with filledcurves {options}
```

which is needed to support filling the area between two curves.  Since the second y value is not initialized in your example, it remains zero and affects the autoscaled range on y.

In the development version (and in the -rc1 for 5.4, which you should download and test) a work-around is to force the `closed` option even though there are three columns of input:

```
  plot $data using 1:2:2 with filledcurves closed
```

Unfortunately version 5.2 doesn't accept `closed` as a keyword here.  So yeah, it's a bug.

If you happen to know the coordinates of some point in the interior (e.g. [7,7] in this case) then you also could use the option:

```
 plot $data using 1:2 with filledcurves xy=7,7
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification and the workaround. I tried to get the `[7,7]` or something else from the data itself, e.g. `plot $Data u (a=$1):(b=$2) w filledcurves xy=a,b` but unfortunately it doesn't work.